# How to access extreme points through the qhull c++ interface

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, qhull

I've inherited a piece of code that uses qhull to create the delaunay triangulation of a set of points. For an extension of the code I want to use the extreme points of the triangulation (the points on the 'outside'), but I can't find how to acquire those through the c++ interface. I did find that the 'Fx' flag can print the extreme points, but I would like to access them through a variable.

The code itself is too big to post here, so I'll add the relevant lines that are already present in the code:

```
#include <libqhull.h>
...
sprintf(flags,"qhull d Qbb Qt T0");
int qh_error = qh_new_qhull(dimension, in_box.size(), pt_array, ismalloc, flags, NULL, errfile);
```

After this, properties of the triangulation are accessed through for example `qh_facetarea` and `qh_pointid`.

What would be the easiest way to access the extreme points, given this code?

Comment: If you make a [mcve] it'll be easier to help - especially for those of us who's never worked with `qhull` before.

Comment: The extreme points are the vertices of the convex hull, no ?

Comment: The convex hull will not help to create a delaunay tessellation. A delaunay tessellation is limited to the convex hull of a point set though, but even then you need to calculate the outline of resultant tessellation.